# Пол, выкрашенный под паркет

Tags: общие-вопросы

"Квартира состояла из четырех комнат  и кухни.  Старая  пыльная мебель, некогда  позолоченная,  была небрежно  расставлена  кругом  стен,  обтянутых  обоями,  на которых изображены были на  зеленом грунте красные попугаи и золотые   лиры;  изразцовые  печи  кое-где  порастрескались; сосновый пол, **выкрашенный  под паркет**, в иных местах скрипел довольно   подозрительно;   в  простенках  висели   овальные зеркала  с  рамками  рококо; вообще комнаты  имели  какую-то странную несовременную наружность."
Помогите разобраться, что значит выкрашенный под паркет? Спасибо!

Comment: Без комментария. Вначале вопрос был таким: "Сосновый пол, выкрашенный под паркет... Помогите разобраться, что значит выкрашенный под паркет?"

Comment: Извините, Shampar, я просто прочитал ваше сообщение и решил исправить своё.

Comment: Всё нормально. Моё "Без комментария" для тех, кто заглянет сюда когда-нибудь, зачем-нибудь.

Answer (score 1):

Фразу следовало бы частью взять в кавычки: Сосновый пол, выкрашенный "под паркет". Тогда было б понятно, что это приём такой, из-за малого бюджета, видимо.

Comment: Вряд ли из-за малого бюджета. См. : _В зале блестящий пол, выкрашенный под паркет, венские стулья, рояль, пюпитр для скрипки. Пахло краской. На стене в золотой раме висела большая картина, написанная красками: нагая дама и около нее лиловая ваза с отбитой ручкой._  (Чехов)

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. Однако, "пахло краской" — слова ключевые: потёмкинская  деревня описана во всей красе.

Comment: По пространному отрывку из повести становится очевидным, что в отделке и убранстве жилища, некогда шикарном (печи с изразцами, стены со шпалерами и пр.), хозяева сэкономили исключительно на паркете. Возможно, не в деньгах, а во времени.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо имеется в виду, что пол выкрасили так, чтобы казалось, что это паркет.